# ¿Cómo hacer para mostrar una sola imagen para varias categorías?

Tags: javascript

Resulta que tengo este código, el cual me recorre un array de una API. Al imprimir en el HTML me repite algunas de las plataformas ya que estas pueden ser por ejemplo: *PlayStation 1*, *PlayStation 2*, etc. Quisiera que solo me apareciera un logo sin importar la plataforma, me explico: si es *ps2* y *ps3* solo quiero que me salga un logo para esos dos.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
        const listaplataformas = document.createElement('img');
        listaplataformas.classList.add('plataformas__li');
        if (textoPlataformas[i].platform.name === 'PC') {
            listaplataformas.src = 'img/windows.png'
        }else if(textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('PlayStation')){
            listaplataformas.src = 'img/ps.png';
        }else if(textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Android')){
            listaplataformas.src = 'img/android.png'
        }else if(textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Xbox')){
            listaplataformas.src = 'img/xbox.png'
        }else if (textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Wii')){
            listaplataformas.src = 'img/wii.png'
        }else if (textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Nintendo')){
            listaplataformas.src = 'img/nintendo.png'
        }else {
            listaplataformas.remove()
        }
        plataformas.appendChild(listaplataformas);        
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es mucho pero mucho mas facil tener un array con todas las plataformas, asociadas a un booleano, y que esten todas apagadas por defecto.. y solo vas prendido a medida que las encontras.. si varios nombres son de la misma, pues se prendera una sola vez...

Comment: es que esa info viene de la API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let bpc = true, bps = true, ban = true,
    bxb = true, bwi = true, bni = true;
for ( let i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++ ) {
    const listaplataformas = document.createElement('img');
    listaplataformas.classList.add('plataformas__li');
    if (textoPlataformas[i].platform.name === 'PC' && bpc ) {
        listaplataformas.src = 'img/windows.png'
        bpc = false;
    }else if(textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('PlayStation') && bps ){
        listaplataformas.src = 'img/ps.png';
        bps = false;
    }else if(textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Android') && ban ){
        listaplataformas.src = 'img/android.png'
        ban = false;
    }else if(textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Xbox') && bxb ){
        listaplataformas.src = 'img/xbox.png'
        bxb = false;
    }else if (textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Wii') && bwi ){
        listaplataformas.src = 'img/wii.png'
        bwi = false;
    }else if (textoPlataformas[i].platform.name.includes('Nintendo') && bni ){
        listaplataformas.src = 'img/nintendo.png'
        bni = false;
    }else {
        listaplataformas.remove()
    }
    plataformas.appendChild(listaplataformas);        
}
```

Solo necesitas agregar unos booleanos, para verificar si una imagen ya está cargada.